# Finding special characters in name

Tags: find, regular-expression

How do I find files that have ~ * and other special characters in the name?

e.g.

```
find . -name "*\*"
```

should match "any characters" and then `*`, but it matches nothing; how can I get the command to correctly match the files?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what operating system you are using. There are significant differences between different implementations of `find`. ii) Show us the files it was supposed to find and didn't. iii) Tell us the shell you are using to run this from (is that bash?).

Comment: When you [edit], please also clarify what you mean by "other special characters".  We have no idea what you consider to be 'special'...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementations of `find` vary, but they should all handle character classes in wildcards (POSIX.2, section 3.13):

```
find . -name '*[~*]*'
```

If newline is among your "special" characters, you may need to work out how to get your shell to pass it to find.  In Bash, you can use

```
find . -name $'*[\t \n]*'
```

to show files containing whitespace, for example.  A simpler method, if supported, is to use a character class:

```
find . -name '*[[:space:]]*'
```

Comment: The POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something more general than matching a specific character, you would have to use regular expressions.  Since the question is not tagged "linux", the proper answer would use POSIX:

```
find . | grep '[*~]'
```

If you want to make it Linux-specific, you can use the GNU `find` option `-regex` (also supported by [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find%281%29)).  If the pathname has an embedded newline (*rarely* done, but used as a *frequent* counterexample), POSIX `find`+`grep` will not work.  But with the `-regex` extension, this "works" to print names which have embedded newlines:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex '.*[*~]'
```

although the manner in which find is *used* is not part of the question.

Further reading:

- [find - find files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (POSIX)
- [find - search for files in a directory hierarchy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (GNU)

Comment: this does not match file with name "~*"

Comment: @ThomasDickey: This fails if file name contains newline.